# Selecting google cloud tool for executing demanding python script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Where should I execute a python script that process ~7giga of data that is available on GCS. The output will be writen to GCS as well.
The script was debugged on datalab notebook with small dataset. I would like to scale up the processing. Should I allocate a big machine? I have no idea what size (resources) of machine is needed.

Many thanks,
Eila

Just in case, 
Dataflow can’t work for that kind of data processing

Comment: It definitely looks like a work for Dataflow or Dataproc though it might be achieved on a single machine too. is the data splitted in files? can it be processed in parallel? Why do you say Dataflow is not fit for the job?

Comment: It is an HDF5 file (batch) that i am converting into a one element row using H5py, numpy and pandas. What will be the guidelines to run the conversion with dataproc. When I run this on datalab, I mount gs:// bucket to the datalab docker machine - Can I do it also with dataproc? Thanks, Eila

Comment: HDF5 is hierarchical data model that does not follow the element wise template and able to compress the file, but there are ways to convert it to element = row (the file will be bigger) and thats what i am doing in my code. for the next steps I will probably use dataflow

Comment: Depends how demanding your processing step is. 7 Gigabytes isn't a large file. If the processing is demanding it would probably simplier to parallelize the processing code and read/write the data in a single thread. 100 MB/s read/write aren't a real problem on a HDD of a Desktop PC if you do everything the right way. (proper chunkcache, avoiding fancy indexing,...)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read about HDF5, it seems that it is not easily parallelizable (See [Parallel HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html) and h5py [multiprocessing_example](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/examples/multiprocessing_example.py#L17)) so I'll assume that reading that ~7GB must me done by one worker.

If there is no workaround to it, and you do not encounter memory issues while processing it on the machine you are already using, I do not see a need to [upgrade your datalab instance](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/machine-type).